# Element not being passed between Xaml pages C#

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, parameter-passing

I have a three page project that consists of MainPage, Menu2 and Menu3.
MainPage is primary but all three pages should work as even to each other.

Navigation and element passing can be done between each of them:
MainPage passign to Menu2
Menu2 passing to Menu3
Menu3 passing to MainPage
and all other possibilities.

I managed to pass element from MainPage to Menu2. Returning of the element works perfectly.
Then I also managed to pass element from Menu2 to Menu3. Returning of that element works too.

Passing doesn't work in such case:

I pass element from MainPage to Menu2. Then I pass element from Menu2 to Menu3. Instead of returning element from Menu3 to Menu2 I attempt to pass it on to MainPage. It doesn't work.

Is there solution for this logic?

I can provide code if needed.

Basicaly the problem is that I cannot pass element from Menu3 to MainPage after it was assigned from Menu2. 
So, I set element within Menu2, navigate to Menu3 (element is being passed), then change value within Menu3 and try to pass it on to MainPage (here element gets lost).

update:

I didn't realize but I actualy use MVVM by making all connections between the View and View Model through bindings in Xaml.

I include some of my code logic:

I have ListBox within each page and the button at the top which' content is set to last listbox selection:

```
firstElement.Content
```

is the content of the MainPage button. It is assigned the value of listbox position selected by user.

I pass this information to Menu2 like this:

```
private void Button2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Create PassData object
        PassData passData = new PassData();

        // Set the InitializeData property from the ListBox
        passData.Data = firstElement.Content;
        passData.Data2 = secondElement.Content;
        passData.Data3 = thirdElement.Content;

        // Pass that object to Navigate
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Menu2), passData);

    }
```

The:

```
secondElement
```

and
`thirdElement` respond to Menu2 and Menu3 pages' buttons respectively.

This is how I retrieve MainPage selection content within Menu2:

```
// pulling data from first page selection
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)
    {
        // Get the object passed as the second argument to Navigate
        PassData passData = args.Parameter as PassData;

        // Use that to initilize the button
        firstElement.Content = passData.Data;
        secondElement.Content = passData.Data2;
        thirdElement.Content = passData.Data3;

        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);

    }
```

After `Button2Click`  the Menu2 is brought to the view. Its button1 contains data pulled from MainPage. It also contains new listbox with new data. Selection of the item within listbox affects the Menu2's button2's content.

Then I navigate to Menu3 like this:

```
private void Button3Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Create PassData object
        PassData passData = new PassData();

        // Set the InitializeCPU property from the ListBox
        passData.Data = firstElement.Content;
        passData.Data2 = secondElement.Content;
        passData.Data3 = thirdElement.Content;

        // Pass that object to Navigate
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Menu3), passData);

    }
```

Both `firstElement.Content` and `secondElement.Content` are being passed on to Menu3 without problems.

Here comes the trouble. If I navigate from Menu3 to Menu2, the data for all three buttons is preserved and returned correctly.

Instead of doing this, I need to navigate from Menu3 to MainPage and preserve the data. In case of secondElement.Content it works, but thirdElement.Content is lost somewhere.

If I put this within MainPage(as within Menu2 for example to retrieve data):

```
PassData passData = args.Parameter as PassData;

        // Use that to initilize the button
        firstElement.Content = passData.Data;
        secondElement.Content = passData.Data2;
        thirdElement.Content = passData.Data3;

        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
```

I get error on launch: `{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`

Comment: Why don't you use a viewmodel that is used in all your pages?

Comment: I am not familiar with viewmodel.

Comment: do I need to always pass element through MainPage? Can I not just pass on as many times as I need?